# How can I return value for a string list?

Tags: c#

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(
                () => textBox4.AppendText(getman(textBox3.Text)));
            t.Start();


        }

        List<string> getman(string url)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0";
                r.Method = "GET";
                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
                string oku = sr.ReadToEnd();

                Regex regex = new Regex(textBox1.Text + "(.*?)" + textBox2.Text);
                MatchCollection m = regex.Matches(oku);
                foreach (Match match in m)
                {
                    result.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString() + "\r\n");
                }

                res.Close();
                sr.Close();

            }
            catch {  }

            return result;
        }
```

It gives the following errors:

```
Error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.AppendText(string)' has some invalid arguments
Error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'
```

Comment: `getman` returns a list, what is it that you're expecting it to do?

Answer (score -1):

As MSDN says (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx) `Append` method does not have a overload for `List<string>` as you are trying to do. That is your main problem.

I do not know exactly what you are trying to accomplish with that code, but if you want your TextBox to be filled with what your list have inside, here is an example of how to do it separating each item by commas:

```
    string getman(string url)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0";
            r.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
            string oku = sr.ReadToEnd();

            Regex regex = new Regex(textBox1.Text + "(.*?)" + textBox2.Text);
            MatchCollection m = regex.Matches(oku);
            foreach (Match match in m)
            {
                result.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString() + "\r\n");
            }

            res.Close();
            sr.Close();

        }
        catch {  }

        return String.Join(",", result.ToArray());
    }
```

Apart from all this, it seems that even if your code seems OK, you are doing Threading work manipulating UI controls that have been for sure created in another thread, since the thread where you are accesing them is declared right there. For Thread Safe calls to your UI, check this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You have to loop through the list and append each string individually:

```
foreach(string line in getman(TextBox3.Text))
{
    TextBox4.AppendText(line);
}
```

Additionally, controls are picky about which threads you use for that stuff. You'll likely need to `Invoke` the TextBox4 control before things really work properly.